# Visual Studio 2013 c++ Web service client

Tags: c++, web-services, visual-studio-2013

I am currently trying to create a win32 console application (in visual studio 2013) that will connect to a weather webservice to retrieve some data.

I have done some research, and there are some examples to add a web reference to the project but for previous version of VS, I would really appreciate some help on how to do this, since it's been driving me crazy! thank you!

Comment: What's a "web reference"?

Comment: are you looking for `ftp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Casablanca REST API** from Microsoft to do that.

Comment: Unless he want to access a SOAP web service

Comment: Thanks!, you have put me in the right path, i already triad to send a request to the api, and i get the response i wanted (JSON), now I just wonder how can I parse that response and just extract the bits I need, do you know how to do this! :)

Comment: Casablanca does include JSON parser. utility::stringstream_t ss1;
json::value v1 = json::value::parse(ss1);

Comment: Check this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/603810/Using-Casablanca-to-consume-a-REST-API